# When passing input data as arrays, do not specify `steps_per_epoch`/`steps` argument. Please use `batch_size` instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My code is below :

```
model.fit_generator(generator=(train_image_list, train_mask_list),epochs=1000,shuffle=True)
```

Both the train_image_list and train_mask_list contains image lists.When trying to run the above code in Google Colab I get the following error:

```
When passing input data as arrays, do not specify `steps_per_epoch`/`steps` argument. Please use `batch_size` instead.
```

In the Keras documentation, fit_generator() do not specify a parameter called 'batch_size'. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please include more code and the entire error message?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you should use the normal `fit()` method, and specify the `batch_size` argument rather than passing arrays as generators.

```
model.fit(train_image_list, train_mask_list, epochs=1000, batch_size=32)
```

From the documentation of [`fit_generator()`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/):

> generator: A generator or an instance of Sequence
>   (keras.utils.Sequence) object in order to avoid duplicate data when
>   using multiprocessing. **The output of the generator** must be either
>   a tuple (inputs, targets)...

You're passing arrays, not a *generator* object. So Keras is telling you that you can't use `fit_generator` this way.