# fit_generator issue using Neural Structured learning

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, nsl

I passed two days trying to use Neural Structured language to adapt into me CNN Model I use ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory when I use model.fit_generator I got an error message:
ValueError:

> When passing input data as arrays, do not specify
> `steps_per_epoch`/`steps` argument. Please use `batch_size` instead.

I use Keras 2.3.1 and TensorFlow 2.0 as backend

This is a snipped of my code:

```
num_classes = 4
img_rows, img_cols = 224, 224
batch_size = 16

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
  rescale=1./255,
  rotation_range=30,
  width_shift_range=0.3,
  height_shift_range=0.3,
  horizontal_flip=True,
  fill_mode='nearest')

  validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
    batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')

    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
    batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')

    def vgg():
      model1 = Sequential([ ])
      return model1

base_model = vgg()
```

## I adapte Datagenerated from (x,y) format to a dictionary format

```
def convert_training_data_generator():
   for x ,y in train_generator:
    return {'feature': x, 'label':y}

def convert_testing_data_generator():
   for x ,y in validation_generator:
    return {'feature': x, 'label': y}

adv_config = nsl.configs.make_adv_reg_config(multiplier=0.2, adv_step_size=0.05)
model = nsl.keras.AdversarialRegularization(base_model, adv_config=adv_config)
train= convert_training_data_generator()
test= convert_testing_data_generator()

history = model.fit_generator(train,
   steps_per_epoch= nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs = epochs,
    callbacks = callbacks,
    validation_data = test,
    validation_steps = nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

Comment: Did you try to you as an argument BATCH_SIZE instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218782/when-passing-input-data-as-arrays-do-not-specify-steps-per-epoch-steps-argu) there is the same error. Maybe you should consider using instead `model.fit()` function. You should define in that case your `train input` your `train labels` and the `batch_size`. In order to figure out the difference between `fit` and `fit_generator`, you can follow that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218782/when-passing-input-data-as-arrays-do-not-specify-steps-per-epoch-steps-argu).

Comment: unfortunately, i can't use **model.fit** because i have a large dataset

Comment: Are you sure also that fit_generator wants this type of input? Have you tried instead to input a list of two arrays?

Comment: thinks for your reply Neural Structured learning assumes that its input batch to be a dictionary containing both x and y, while ImageDataGenerator generates input in (x, y) tuples, this is why i use convert_training_data_generator to resolve this issue, and now I got this error **ValueError: Layer model_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'dict'>. Full input: [{'feature': <tf.Tensor 'feature:0' shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>}]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.**